# How to declare a dictionary using a name the user specifies?

Tags: vb.net

Obviously I cannot use strName in the Dictionary declaration line, but I'm just placing it there to represent what I'm trying to do. For example, if the User enters "carrot", I want the dictionary created to be named carrot. Is there a way to do this?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim strName As String
        strName = TextBox1.Text

        Dim strName As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: define the dictionary, `dict`, then `dict.item(strname)=1`; you can make entries to the dictionary for every `strname`.

Comment: Why does the name of the variable matter once the user enters it? At that point the program is running and you shouldn't care about the variable name.

Comment: You can have a `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))`, but there is a good chance that some other data structure would be better. What exactly do you need to store? Why does it matter to the user what the name of the Dictionary variable is? (It doesn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The name is useful for debugging and in reality the compiler will not use the name anyway - the name will be kept in the pdb file, nowhere else.

If you need to keep track of some dictionary by name, you could use another dictionary such as:

```vb
Private dictionaries As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strName = TextBox1.Text
    Dim myNamedDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    If dictionaries.ContainsKey(strName) Then
        myNamedDictionary = dictionaries(strName)
    Else
        myNamedDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        dictionaries.Add(strName, myNamedDictionary)
    End If
    ' now you have a dictionary for the name you entered (carrot)
End Sub
```

To retrieve

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim carrotDictionary = dictionaries("carrot")
End Sub
```

I think this is as close as you will get.

Answer (score 0):

You can, kind of. Using a compiler you can compile your own code, but the end result seems so unusable, I doubt this is what you want to do

```vb
Option Strict Off
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler

Public Class Form1
    Private dictionaryInstance As Object
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim strName = TextBox1.Text
        Dim t = GetType(Form1)
        Dim ns = t.Namespace
        Dim provider = New VBCodeProvider()
        Dim params = New CompilerParameters()
        params.GenerateInMemory = True
        params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
        params.OutputAssembly = "OutputAssembly"
        Dim code =
$"
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Namespace {ns}
Partial Public Class DictionaryClass
    Public {strName} As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
End Namespace"
        Dim results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, {code})
        Dim assy = results.CompiledAssembly
        Dim o As Object = assy.CreateInstance($"{ns}.DictionaryClass")
        Me.dictionaryInstance = o
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        dictionaryInstance.carrot.Add("a", "b")
    End Sub
End Class
```